# Does salesforce require javascript enabled?

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I'm working on a custom visualforce page and it uses javascript/jquery to provide some functionality. Such as some of the fields are not displayed by default and are then displayed by javascript after certain actions. So if the user had javascript disabled in their browser some functionality would not work.

I was about to start trying to find ways to fix this or workaround it but I decided to search and see if salesforce itself does anything about this and there was little documentation but I found this: http://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_supported_browsers_cheatsheet.pdf

And there is a line that says: "For all browsers, you must enable JavaScript, cookies, and SSL 3.0".

Why exactly must you have javascript enabled? If I went through the trouble of fixing certain aspects of my page so that it works even without javascript would it be a moot point since salesforce as a whole requires it?

Comment: I cannot give a definitive answer, but I do know that any given Salesforce page relies heavily on scripting. While I have not tried turning off JavaScript, I would expect the entire site (stock and custom pages) to fail miserably.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Salesforce requires Javascript for sure .If you would have done view source of salesforce pages it would tell you the story .

I think only reason salesforce asks to avoid scripting is because they may interact with some of the Existing Visualforce Tags that may use Javascript at the backend .

So whole world is moving towards Script .The Mobile Hybrid development relies on this technology and I dont see any issue using those .

Comment: Yah I was just looking for maybe a resource stating it for sure so I dont have to tell my boss that I just looked through the source. But youre are defintely right. I just tried running things without javascript disabled on chrome and it appears that it sets everythings style to display: none !important;. Certainly doesnt work to say the least.